# Changing column in HTML table to hyperlink

Tags: php, html-table, text-files

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$lines; $i++) 
{
    //get each line and exlplode it..
    $part = explode('|', $file[$i]);

    //now start printing ..
    echo'<tr>

            <td width="20%">'.$part[0].'</td>

            <td width="20%">'.$part[1].'</td>

            <td width="20%">'.$part[2].'</td>

            <td width="20%">'.$part[3].'</td>

            <td width="20%">'.$part[4].'</td>

        </tr>';
}
```

This is my code, it read's from a text file and explode in table, but I have a little problem here cause this one needs to be link.

```
<td width="20%">'.$part[2].'</td>
```

`.$part[2].` is just a word from file but it has query like `www.somesite.com/?q=` There at the end I need to have that

> word from file

that kind of code did not work for me 
`<td width="20%"> <a herf='www.somesite.com/?q=''.$part[2].'> '.$part[2].' </a> </td>`

I realy need some help with this...

```
<?php

//first, get the file...

$file = file('req.txt');



//now count the lines ..

$lines = count($file);



//start the table here..

echo'<table border="2" width="100%">';

echo'<tr>

              <td width="20%">Naslov</td>

              <td width="20%">Vrsta</td>

              <td width="20%">IP</td>

              <td width="20%">Dodano (DD.MM.YY - HH.MM)</td>

              <td width="20%">Status</td>
         </tr>';


//start the loop to get all lines in the table..

for ($i=0; $i<=$lines; $i++) {



//get each line and exlplode it..

  $part = explode('|', $file[$i]);

//now start printing ..

  echo'<tr>

              <td width="20%">'.$part[0].'</td>

              <td width="20%">'.$part[1].'</td>

              <td width="20%">'.$part[2].'</td>

              <td width="20%">'.$part[3].'</td>

              <td width="20%">'.$part[4].'</td>
         </tr>';

}



//close the table so HTML wont suffer :P

echo'</table>'; 




?>
```

This should produce this but ip column need to be link...
[image: Final Product]

Comment: What was exactly wrong with `<td><a></a></td>`? The `<a>` didn't vertically fill the table cell? BTW, you have a typo in `<a herf=`, it should read `href=`.

Comment: i will test it tomorow, it's late here & i will go to sleep now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it alone with changing some values in input script "file writer"

```
$savestring = $title . "|" . $genre . "|<a href=http://www.example.com/ip?ip=" . $ip . ">" . $ip . "|" . $date . "|Za Nalo&#382;it \n";
```

it works now ty anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I think [`vprintf()`](http://php.net/vprintf) is your friend.

```
<?php

$fmt = '<tr>
    <td>%1$s</td>
    <td>%2$s</td>
    <td><a href="http://example.com/?q=%3$s">%3$s</a></td>
    <td>%4$s</td>
    <td>%5%s</td>
  </tr>';

for ($i=0; $i<=$lines; $i++) 
{
  // get each line and explode it..
  $part = explode('|', $file[$i]);

  // now start printing ..
  vprintf($fmt, $part);
}
```

And put the `width="20%"` into your CSS.

Comment: look at the answer again, i posted full script & result i need

Comment: Your update changes your question from "how do I do this better" to "please make my program work".  I answered your original question.  You should still be able to use my answer to improve that section of your code.